# h,i,b,u tag within p tag cause error in php

Tags: php, html, security

I use a form with textarea to put text in and then write to file via PHP program.
It normally works fine until I hit a situation when some HTML tags, h, b, i, u, style, center etc.
are used inside p.

```
For example this work ok,
<h3>Header></h3>
<p></p>

But the error message below will shown if:
<p><h3>Header</h3></p>

But if I put this way, it also ok:
<p> <h3>Header</h3></p>
```

Can anyone give an explanation? I used Hostgator Baby Plan.

The error message from PHP:
"Not Acceptable!

An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. 
This error was generated by Mod_Security."

Comment: `b`, `i` and `u` should be ok inside `<p>`, but a `h1` (or any other `h`) inside a `p` is not valid HTML.

Comment: You need to share relevant code to your issue. All we see is that you have a problem, but without the code we cannot actually see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The `<p>` tag can only contain inline elements. The `header` tags are block-level elements, and cannot go inside `<p>` tags even when you style them to display inline.

Comment: Thnaks, but the question is PHP know I made mistake in handling the tag? All I do is to send an encoded string to write a file, how came apache Mod_Security generate an error and did not run PHP at all?